# Prevent Netbeans 8.0 from adding Jersey / Glassfish dependencies automatically

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, glassfish, jersey

Surprisingly, I can say after a lot of search that none on earth has ever had this problem, but it's a quite strange behaviour!

I recently moved to Netbeans 8 from eclipse kepler. My environment is Wildfly with Resteasy/Jax-rs. So I do not want or need Jersey, Glassfish or whatever. If I need a new dependency I just add that one to my pom.xml, right?
No, it doesn't seem so, It appears that Netbeans thinks that if you have a web application you **must** have Glassfish and Jersey in your project, so Netbeans add those dependencies automatically in my POMs, and having both resteasy and jersey in my classpath causes just **a few** problems.

I removed all jersey dependencies added to my POMs but sometimes, randomly, when I "mvn install" my project from netbeans I still have Jersey inside my war.

Does anyone know why Jersey is added by default by Netbeans in my classpath.. and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could trick your environment by adding the jersey dependency but mark it as **provided**. So it would be there and Netbeans will not add another one but it is not within your WAR.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>.. jersey ..</groupId>
    <artifactId>.. jersey ..</artifactId>
    <version>.. jersey.version ..</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This seems to be filed as a bug for Netbeanx 7.x (https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=232922) and was **closed**. Maybe you should reopen it, if it is still an issue for Netbeans 8.0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but using runtime dependencies when not needed is not a *clean* solution... I'd prefer to avoid useless dependencies in classpath, even if they are provided. I'll investigate and eventually re-open the bug if I'm able to easily reproduce this issue.. thanks